# JSF não encontra recurso

Tags: xml, jsf

Bom dia.

Não estou conseguindo apresentar uma tela pois é dito que falta um determinado recurso que não é citado através do console e da tela de erro. Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

```
<ui:define name="section">  
    <br />          
    <center><h:outputLabel value="Fluxo de Caixa da Ambiental" class="title" /></center>        
    <br />

    <h:form id="form">
        <p:commandButton value="Novo" icon="ui-icon-document"
            actionListener="#{cenarioBean.novoFluxoAmbiental}" process="@this" update="dataTable fluxoAmbiental-dialog" 
            oncomplete="PF('fluxoAmbientalDialog').show()" class="botaoDataTable">
            <p:resetInput target="fluxoAmbiental-dialog" />
        </p:commandButton>

        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" 
            id="btnEditar" title="Editar" disabled="#{cenarioBean.fluxoAmbiental == null}" 
            class="botaoDataTable" process="@this" update="dataTable :form" 
            oncomplete="PF('fluxoAmbientalDialog').show()">
            <p:resetInput target="fluxoAmbiental-dialog" />
        </p:commandButton>

        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" 
            id="btnExcluir" title="Excluir" disabled="#{cenarioBean.fluxoAmbiental == null}" class="botaoDataTable" 
            action="#{cenarioBean.excluirFluxoAmbiental}" process="@this" update="dataTable btnExcluir btnEditar"/> 

        <p:commandButton value="Resumo" icon="ui-icon-document"
            actionListener="#{cenarioBean.calcularResumo}" process="@this" update="dataTable resumo-dialog" 
            oncomplete="PF('resumoDialog').show()" class="botaoDataTable"/>

        <h:outputText value="Campos com a cor vermelha não são editáveis ou excluíveis" class="mensagemSobreDatatable naoEditavel" style="font-size:130% !important; color: #fff !important;"/>

        <p:dataTable var="f" value="#{cenarioBean.fluxos}" 
            paginator="true" rows="10" class="dataTable" id="dataTable"
            emptyMessage="Nenhum Fluxo de Ambiental Cadastrado" paginatorPosition="bottom" 
            selection="#{cenarioBean.fluxoAmbiental}" selectionMode="single" 
            rowKey="#{f.idFluxoAmbiental}" rowStyleClass="#{cenarioBean.verificarFluxoEditavel(f)}">

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"  updtate=":form:btnEditar :form:btnExcluir"/>
            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" updtate=":form:btnEditar :form:btnExcluir"/>

            <p:column headerText="Ano">
                <h:outputText value="#{f.anoFluxoAmbiental}"/>
            </p:column>                 

            <p:column headerText="Tipo de Fluxo">
                <h:outputText value="#{f.tipoFluxoAmbiental}"/>
            </p:column>             

            <p:column headerText="Valor Receita (R$)">
                <h:outputText value="#{f.valorReceitaFluxoAmbiental}"/>
            </p:column> 

            <p:column headerText="Tipo Receita">
                <h:outputText value="#{f.tipoReceitaFluxoAmbiental}"/>
            </p:column> 

            <p:column headerText="Valor Despesa (R$)">
                <h:outputText value="#{f.valorDespesaFluxoAmbiental}"/>
            </p:column> 

            <p:column headerText="Tipo Despesa">
                <h:outputText value="#{f.tipoDespesaFluxoAmbiental}"/>
            </p:column> 

            <p:column headerText="Impostos (R$)">
                <h:outputText value="#{f.impostosFluxoAmbiental}"/>
            </p:column>                 
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:dialog header="Fluxo de Caixa da Ambiental" widgetVar="fluxoAmbientalDialog" id="fluxoAmbiental-dialog"
                resizable="false" modal="true" closeOnEscape="true" width="500">
            <p:panelGrid style="width:100%;" id="painel">                                           
                <p:row>
                    <p:column><h:outputLabel for="anoFluxoAmbiental" value="Ano do Fluxo de Ambiental: " class="componentePF label" /></p:column>
                    <p:column><p:spinner id="anoFluxoAmbiental" value="#{cenarioBean.fluxoAmbiental.anoFluxoAmbiental}" min="0" class="componentePF text" style="width:100% !important;"/></p:column>
                </p:row>    

                <p:row>
                    <p:column><h:outputLabel for="impostosFluxoAmbiental" value="Impostos: " class="componentePF label" /></p:column>
                    <p:column><p:spinner id="impostosFluxoAmbiental" value="#{cenarioBean.fluxoAmbiental.impostosFluxoAmbiental}" min="0" prefix="R$ " class="componentePF text" style="width:100% !important;"/></p:column>
                </p:row>    

                <p:row>
                    <p:column><h:outputLabel for="tipoFluxoAmbiental" value="Tipo do Fluxo: " class="componentePF label" /></p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoFluxoAmbiental" value="#{cenarioBean.fluxoAmbiental.tipoFluxoAmbiental}" 
                            class="componentePF text" required="true" requiredMessage="É necessário escolher um tipo">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolha um Tipo de Fluxo" noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Receita" itemValue="Receita" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Despesa" itemValue="Despesa" />    

                            <p:ajax event="change" update=":form:receita :form:despesa :form:painel"/>               
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>                

                <!-- CAMPOS PARA RECEITA -->                        
                <p:row rendered="#{cenarioBean.verificarTipoReceita()}" id="receita">
                    <p:column><h:outputLabel for="valorReceitaFluxoAmbiental" value="Valor da Receita: " class="componentePF label" /></p:column>
                    <p:column><p:spinner id="valorReceitaFluxoAmbiental" value="#{cenarioBean.fluxoAmbiental.valorReceitaFluxoAmbiental}" min="0" prefix="R$ " class="componentePF text" style="width:100% !important;"/></p:column>
                </p:row>    

                <p:row rendered="#{cenarioBean.verificarTipoReceita()}">    
                    <p:column><h:outputLabel for="tipoReceitaFluxoAmbiental" value="Tipo de Receita " class="componentePF label" /></p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoReceitaFluxoAmbiental" value="#{cenarioBean.fluxoAmbiental.tipoReceitaFluxoAmbiental}" class="componentePF text">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolha um tipo de Receita" noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Equipamento" itemValue="Equipamento" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Pessoal" itemValue="Pessoal"/>
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Jurídica" itemValue="Juridica"/>
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Outros" itemValue="Outros"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>

                <!-- CAMPOS PARA DESPESA -->                        
                <p:row rendered="#{!cenarioBean.verificarTipoReceita()}" id="despesa">
                    <p:column><h:outputLabel for="valorDespesaFluxoAmbiental" value="Valor da Despesa: " class="componentePF label" /></p:column>
                    <p:column><p:spinner id="valorDespesaFluxoAmbiental" value="#{cenarioBean.fluxoAmbiental.valorDespesaFluxoAmbiental}" min="0" prefix="R$ " class="componentePF text" style="width:100% !important;"/></p:column>
                </p:row>    

                <p:row rendered="#{!cenarioBean.verificarTipoReceita()}">   
                    <p:column><h:outputLabel for="tipoDespesaFluxoAmbiental" value="Tipo de Despesa: " class="componentePF label" /></p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoDespesaFluxoAmbiental" value="#{cenarioBean.fluxoAmbiental.tipoDespesaFluxoAmbiental}" class="componentePF text">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolha um tipo de Despesa" noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Custos Operacionais" itemValue="Custos Operacionais"/>
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Custos Administrativos" itemValue="Custos Administrativos" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Outros" itemValue="Outros"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>

                <p:row>
                    <p:column colspan="2">
                        <p:commandButton value="Cadastrar" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                            action="#{cenarioBean.cadastrarFluxoAmbiental}" id="cadastrarFluxoAmbiental"
                            ajax="false" class="componentePF button" process="@this"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>  
        </p:dialog>

        <p:dialog header="Resumo do Fluxo de Caixa"
            widgetVar="resumoDialog" id="resumo-dialog"
            resizable="false" modal="true" closeOnEscape="true" width="850">

            <p:dataTable var="r" value="#{cenarioBean.resumos}" style="width:100% !important; margin:0% !important;"
                paginator="true" rows="10" class="dataTable" id="dataTable2"
                paginatorPosition="bottom">

            <p:column headerText="Ano">
                <h:outputText value="#{r.ano}"/>
            </p:column> 

            <p:column headerText="Saldo Inicial">
                <h:outputText value="#{r.saldoInicial}"/>
            </p:column> 

            <p:column headerText="Saldo Final">
                <h:outputText value="#{r.saldoFinal}"/>
            </p:column> 

            </p:dataTable>              
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Tela do erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Console

```
Set 10, 2015 8:30:43 AM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
ADVERTÊNCIA: JSF1064: Não foi possível encontrar ou fornecer o recurso, /restrito/suporte/concessao/fluxoAmbiental.xhtml.
Set 10, 2015 8:30:43 AM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
ADVERTÊNCIA: JSF1064: Não foi possível encontrar ou fornecer o recurso, /restrito/suporte/concessao/fluxoAmbiental.view.xml.
Set 10, 2015 8:30:43 AM com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl getMimeType
ADVERTÊNCIA: JSF1091: Nenhum tipo de mime pôde ser encontrado para o arquivo /restrito/suporte/concessao/fluxoAmbiental.jsp.  Para resolver isso, adicione um mapeamento de mime-type ao web.xml do aplicativo.
Set 10, 2015 8:30:43 AM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
ADVERTÊNCIA: JSF1064: Não foi possível encontrar ou fornecer o recurso, /restrito/suporte/concessao/fluxoAmbiental.jsp.
Set 10, 2015 8:30:43 AM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
ADVERTÊNCIA: JSF1064: Não foi possível encontrar ou fornecer o recurso, /restrito/suporte/concessao/fluxoAmbiental.xhtml.
Set 10, 2015 8:30:43 AM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
ADVERTÊNCIA: JSF1064: Não foi possível encontrar ou fornecer o recurso, /restrito/suporte/concessao/fluxoAmbiental.view.xml.
Set 10, 2015 8:30:43 AM com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl getMimeType
ADVERTÊNCIA: JSF1091: Nenhum tipo de mime pôde ser encontrado para o arquivo /restrito/suporte/concessao/fluxoAmbiental.jsp.  Para resolver isso, adicione um mapeamento de mime-type ao web.xml do aplicativo.
Set 10, 2015 8:30:43 AM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
ADVERTÊNCIA: JSF1064: Não foi possível encontrar ou fornecer o recurso, /restrito/suporte/concessao/fluxoAmbiental.jsp.
```

Pede que adicione um mapeamento mime type e identifica minha página com .jsp. Esse problema não acontece em absolutamente nenhuma das outras telas que tenho.

Grato!

Comment: Qual versão de JSF e Primefaces tu esta utilizando?

Comment: Estou usando a 2.2 e 5, respectivamente.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi.

Eu tinha renomeado meu xhtml de fluxoambiental para fluxoAmbiental, isso fez com que houvesse um problema com algumas variáveis que criei. Depois que troquei o nome do arquivo para fluxoCaixaAmbiental.xhtml funcionou beleza.